# How to get multiple edited rows using "ag Grid" | Angualr

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to identify which rows edited by the user and save only edited rows to the server through REST API.So can someone explain me to the right way of getting edited rows form the list?

as per my understanding, I have added one variable `{ isEdited: false}` in the dataset, if user edited one of the cells then explicitly set this variable from false to true and on save button I will iterate the list and get records which have `isEdited=true`

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { CustomcellDropdownComponent } from '../customcell-dropdown/customcell-dropdown.component';
import { AllCommunityModules, Module } from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cellediting-container',
  templateUrl: './cellediting-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cellediting-container.component.css']
})
export class CelleditingContainerComponent {

  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;

  private columnDefs;
  private components;
  private rowData;
  private editType;
  private editingRowIndex;

  constructor() {
    this.setDefinition();
    // this.components = { numericCellEditor: this.getNumericCellEditor() };
    this.rowData = this.getRowData();
    this.editType = "cell";
  }

  onCellClicked($event) {
    // check whether the current row is already opened in edit or not
    if (this.editingRowIndex != $event.rowIndex) {
      console.log($event);
      $event.api.startEditingCell({
        rowIndex: $event.rowIndex,
        colKey: $event.column.colId
      });
      this.editingRowIndex = $event.rowIndex;
    }
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
  setDefinition() {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Make",
        field: "make",
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
        rowDrag: true,
        cellEditorParams: {
          values: ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
        }
      },
      {
        headerName: "Model",
        field: "model",
        editable: true
      },
      {
        headerName: "Price",
        field: "price",
        editable: true,
        // cellEditor: "numericCellEditor"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Suppress Navigable",
        field: "field5",
        editable: true,
        suppressNavigable: true
      },
      {
        headerName: "Not Editable",
        field: "field6",
        editable: false
      }
    ];
  }
  getRowData() {
    var rowData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      rowData.push({
        make: "Toyota",
        model: "Celica",
        price: 35000 + i * 1000,
        field5: "Sample 22",
        field6: "Sample 23",
        vm: { isEdited: null }
      });
      rowData.push({
        make: "Ford",
        model: "Mondeo",
        price: 32000 + i * 1000,
        field5: "Sample 24",
        field6: "Sample 25",
        vm: { isEdited: null }
      });
      rowData.push({
        make: "Porsche",
        model: "Boxter",
        price: 72000 + i * 1000,
        field5: "Sample 26",
        field6: "Sample 27",
        vm: { isEdited: null }
      });
    }
    return rowData;
  }

  // fucntion for save data

  saveData() {
    console.log('save data executed', this.rowData);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <button (click)="saveData()">Save</button>
</div>
<div style="height: 500px; padding-top: 30px; box-sizing: border-box;">
    <ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowDragManaged]="true"
    [animateRows]="true"
    [components]="components"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [editType]="editType"
    (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Comment: If you found any answers, please share and kick me:)

Answer (score 0):

There are handy `onCellValueChanged(event: CellValueChangedEvent)` and `onRowValueChanged(event: RowValueChangedEvent)` events as a part of `GridOptions` object. In your case, you can bind a handler for it by using `this.gridApi.onRowValueChanged = (event: CellValueChangedEvent) => { };` and add the required implementation inside.